# Override default template files

Tags: template, frontend

I am trying to implement an adjustment to the default .phtml files that are shipped with magento. I am a little confused as to how the .phtml files are altered without adjusting them directly, consequently I am failing to get this to work. The example I will use is the account dashboard heading (found on `storeName.local/index.php/customer/account/index/`) MY ACCOUNT, I'd like to change it to [USERSNAME]'S ACCOUNT.

To do this I have copied the contents of `customer/account/navigation.phtml` into the file path `myNamespace/modulename/account/navigation.phtml` on line 29 there is this code

```
<?php echo $this->__('My Account'); ?> my random text for testing
```

and added this to my modulename/layout.xml

```
    <modulename_index_index>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="namespace/modulename/account/navigation.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </modulename_index_index>
```

THEN

```
    <modulename_index_index>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="insert"><type>simple</type><block>customer/account_navigation</block><template>namespace/modulename/account/navigation.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    <modulename_index_index>
```

These methods have not worked. To be honest I didn't expect it to but the way I have read the posts is that I need to apply the code from the phtml file which I am overriding into my module, followed by the equivalent file path held in its default module.

How do I go about making adjustments

Pages viewed to try and resolve issue

[try 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1411/calling-custom-phtml-file-in-footer) [try 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909702/magento-including-a-custom-phtml-file-in-view-phtml) [try 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230672/override-product-price-template-in-magento)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know the heading is located in the file `customer/account/dashboard.phtml`. To overwrite this from your custom extensions layout XML, or the `local.xml` please add the following

```
<customer_account_index>
   <reference name="customer_account_dashboard">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>[module]/customer/account/dashboard.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

This will change the template file used from the default file to your custom file which, in this case, would be located at `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/[module]/customer/account/dashboard.phtml`

Comment: This is what I was trying to achieve, but I am unable to add my additional text with your suggested code, I edited `customer.xml` to make sure I was targeting the right location and using namespace/module/restOfThePath it worked, I applied this to `local.xml` and that had no effect. Where else would you suggest looking to resolve the issue?

Comment: might be that the view file is already overwritten somewhere. Did you try and turn on template hints to see if the origional file is used in your shop?

Comment: I had previously other overrides in local xml, within a default node (come to think about it I don't know why I didn't consider this option before), the suggestion you offered was placed in a default node by me, taking it out sees your code working perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I may have confused you earlier with my [overly long post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8957/3408).

Start by creating a new theme.  Note the base theme is a folder called `app/design/frontend/default/base/`.  Let's pretend your theme is "tony" and create a folder called `app/design/frontend/default/tony/`.  Now go to the Magento admin, click on the menu System > Configuration, then click on Design.  Fill the page in like this before saving.

[image]

Your new theme is now active but looks exactly like the base theme.  Copy the file `app/design/frontend/default/base/customer/account/navigation.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/default/tony/customer/account/navigation.phtml`.  Make some edits to the new file and look again at your site, it should have changed!

If not go to the admin menu System > Cache Management and turn off all caches until you have finished working on the site.

Comment: Although this is one way to do it OP was actually right on track with overwriting it from a custom extension which is, in my opinion, much cleaner.

Comment: It depends what you are trying to achieve.  I like having both answers here for future reference and comparison.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it's good to state both options :)

Comment: I shall be trying this as a way to give myself a fuller understanding of what options are available to me in the future, thank you